# Oracle and optional stored procedure parameter in where clause

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with an optional parameter like this

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE "my_stored_procedure" (param1 int, param2 int default null)
IS

BEGIN 

[select some fields from some tables]
...
```

I need a `where` clause with a if on the default parameter (if it is set), but I don't even know if it's possible...

Something like

```
where param1=123 and (if param2 is not null then some_value != param2)
```

The `select` clause it's pretty long and complex, so I'll prefer to have a "flexible" `WHERE` rather than a structure like

```
if param2 is not null then
    [long and complex select] where param1=123 and some_value != param2
else
    [long and complex select] where param1=123
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can do:

```
where param1=123 and (param2 is null or param2 != some_value)
```

If param2 is not null - then it's true only if `param2 != some_value` - as expected
If param2 is null - then it returns true no matter what `some_value` is

Answer (score 2):

Initially we used this syntax:

```
WHERE (pParameter = COLUMN OR pParameter IS NULL)
```

until a database tuning specialist found out that this causes Oracle to perform full table scans and ignore the indexes, because of using OR.

Now we use

```
WHERE decode(pParameter, 
             null, 1, --if parameter is null, then return 1
             COLUMN, 1, -- if parameter matches the value in the column, then return 1
             0) --else return 0
             = 1
```

this construct allows an easy and readable way to add special handling for special values

```
WHERE decode(pParameter, 
     null, 1, --if parameter is null, then allow the row
     'abc', 1, --if parameter is 'abc', then always allow the row
     'xyz', 1, --if parameter is 'xyz', then always reject the row
     COLUMN, 1, -- if parameter matches the value in the column, then allow
         0) --else return 0 to reject the row
         = 1
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite this with COALESCE or with CASE:

```
WHERE COALESCE(pParameter, COLUMN, 'ok') = COALESCE(COLUMN, 'ok')
```

or, sample using CASE:

```
THEN    (
            case 
            when pParameteris null then 1
            when pParameter= COLUMN then 1
            else 0
            end
        ) = 1
```